# PHP - Take 4 items from one array then 2 from another and merge into an array, recurse until no more items

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I've got 2 arrays, one full of landscape orientation image urls and one full of portrait orientation image urls. They will ultimately be output on the page in an image slide show with each slide comprised of of 4 landscape images and 2 portrait images.

I've already got the images into their arrays, I'm calling them

```
$horizontalImages
$verticalImages
```

Now I want to create a new array that selects the first 4 images from `$horizontalImages`and first 2 images from `$verticalImages` and makes that one entry in the new array. Then recursively chooses the next 4 from `$horizontalImages` and next 2 from `$verticalImages`and makes the next item in the new array and to continue along until there are no more items.

So, pie in the sky example of what I think the data should look like would be something like the following, and please excuse errors here, I'm winging it in terms of what that might look like and I can't even tell if this correct or if it would be multi-dimensions / nested arrays, so clearly I need help understanding the principle of what the structure of this new array would look like.

```
array(x) {
    [0]=>???Array???(x){
       [0]=>"/landscape-image-1.jpg"
       [1]=>"/landscape-image-2.jpg"
       [2]=>"/landscape-image-3.jpg"
       [3]=>"/landscape-image-4.jpg"
       [4]=>"/portrait-image-1.jpg"
       [5]=>"/portrait-image-2.jpg"
    }
    [1]=>???Array???(x){
       [0]=>"/landscape-image-5.jpg"
       [1]=>"/landscape-image-6.jpg"
       [2]=>"/landscape-image-7.jpg"
       [3]=>"/landscape-image-8.jpg"
       [4]=>"/portrait-image-3.jpg"
       [5]=>"/portrait-image-4.jpg"
    }
}
```

Once I've got the array locked down though in a real functioning way, I'd like to put it through a `foreach` loop like:

```
foreach ($myArray as $slide):
$image1 = $slide['0'];
$image2 = $slide['1'];
$image3 = $slide['2'];
$image4 = $slide['3'];
$image5 = $slide['4'];
$image6 = $slide['5'];

// Blah blah HTML output, so on so forth...

endforeach;
```

I hope I've provided enough info. Thanks in advance for any help here.

Here is something I tried, which seems to be sort of working... but I'm getting duplicates and such.

```
$countH = 0;
$countV = 0;

foreach ($horizontalImages as $key => $horizImg):

    $countH++;

       foreach ($verticalImages as $k =>$vertImg):

                    $countV++;

                    if ($countH % 4 == 1):

             $variables[$countH][] = $horizImg; 

                            if ($countV % 2 == 1):
                                $variables[$countH][] = $vertImg; 
                            endif;

                    endif;

       endforeach;
    endforeach;



    <pre>
    <?php var_dump($variables); ?>
    </pre>
```

Results as

```
    array(5) {
  [1]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/f5e4eeec3e2e0a7fcaefdc1c756cdee8_f486.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/08cbd2856e4ecb8f25347540238ff356_f488.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/67c4cb481a31c03626b7289e66515f93_f489.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [9]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
    [10]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/046cb32b0c062a359a71e24e814d5bff_f485.jpg"
    [11]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ff89e524684c8ff50103fefd715e6f46_f473.jpg"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/f5e4eeec3e2e0a7fcaefdc1c756cdee8_f486.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/08cbd2856e4ecb8f25347540238ff356_f488.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/67c4cb481a31c03626b7289e66515f93_f489.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [9]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
    [10]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/046cb32b0c062a359a71e24e814d5bff_f485.jpg"
    [11]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/40a132f198f0648b4b9794505d8a7201_f474.jpg"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/f5e4eeec3e2e0a7fcaefdc1c756cdee8_f486.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/08cbd2856e4ecb8f25347540238ff356_f488.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/67c4cb481a31c03626b7289e66515f93_f489.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [9]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
    [10]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/046cb32b0c062a359a71e24e814d5bff_f485.jpg"
    [11]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c96f867163ec38d83d59350dfdb9518d_f478.jpg"
  }
  [13]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/f5e4eeec3e2e0a7fcaefdc1c756cdee8_f486.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/08cbd2856e4ecb8f25347540238ff356_f488.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/67c4cb481a31c03626b7289e66515f93_f489.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [9]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
    [10]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/046cb32b0c062a359a71e24e814d5bff_f485.jpg"
    [11]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/c09af0f66cb15621163e4018e4c34e72_f479.jpg"
  }
  [17]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/f5e4eeec3e2e0a7fcaefdc1c756cdee8_f486.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/08cbd2856e4ecb8f25347540238ff356_f488.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/67c4cb481a31c03626b7289e66515f93_f489.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [9]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
    [10]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/046cb32b0c062a359a71e24e814d5bff_f485.jpg"
    [11]=>
    string(54) "/files/cache/ba56c501e8f83264894d84a53ce056d1_f467.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like some clever math and `while loop`ing can get this done.

Comment: You know I did a bit, mostly I created the two arrays to store the landscape and portrait images and then just had a total brain meltdown trying to visualize how I would mash them up. I didn't consider using `while` but I guess I could with multiples of 4 and 2 but really it's the merging it into one array that sort of has me stumped... unless I don't have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ch = ceil(count($horizontalImages) / 4);// Count of quartet (including incomplete tuples)
$cv = ceil(count($verticalImages) / 2);// Count of doublet (including incomplete tuples)

$c = $ch>$cv ? $ch : $cv; // Are there more - quartets or doublets?    
$out = array();

// We pass on the long side
for ($x=0;$x<$c;$x++) {
    $tmp1 = $x<$ch ? array_slice($horizontalImages, $x*4, 4) : array(); // No more quartet?
    $tmp2 = $x<$cv ? array_slice($verticalImages, $x*2, 2) : array(); // No more doublet?
    $out[] = array_merge( $tmp1, $tmp2 ); // Fold tuples together
}
```

http://ideone.com/2xaO2q

Comment: Dang... that's really good with the array_slice. Thanks very much, way more clever than anything I was able to come up with.